# Multigrid Interpolation and Restriction operators

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, interpolation, multigrid

I have a question about the restriction and the interpolation operators of a Multigrid algorithm.

Let those be given:

- The full weighting restriction stencil (in 2D): $\frac{1}{16} \left[ \begin{array}{ccc} 1 & 2 & 1 \\ 2 & 4 & 2 \\ 1 & 2 & 1 \end{array} \right] $
- The bilinear interpolation: $\frac{1}{4} \left. \right] \begin{array}{ccc} 1 & 2 & 1 \\ 2 & 4 & 2 \\ 1 & 2 & 1 \end{array} \left[ \right. $

It is always said, that one is the transpose of the other. For the matrix that is pretty obvious, but how come the prefactors differ.

The reason why I ask is the following: I have given the cubic interpolation stencil. And from this, I'd like to know the corresponding restriction operator. The matrix is easy to get, but I'm not sure about the coefficient.

Thanks

Comment: I'm sure that you've come upon this yourself, but my comment is for anyone else who sees this. The coefficient is the coefficient needed in order to restrict a constant vector of $1$s to a constant vector of $1$s on the new grid.

Comment: If you work out the algebra, I think you'll see that the prefactor is irrelevant as long as you are consistent with the application of your interpolation/restriction matrices and generate the coarse grid operator via the Galerkin triple product.  (For example, if your restriction operator has an extra factor of 2 in front, then both your coarse grid operator and your residual will just be twice as large, and the error you compute on the coarse grid will be the same.)